# Show that $ \max \left\{\left|X_{1}\right|, \ldots,\left|X_{n}\right|\right\} \stackrel{\mathrm{P}}{\longrightarrow} a $ for $ n \rightarrow \infty $

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $ X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots $ be independent and $ X_{n} \sim \mathrm{U}(-a, a), a>0 $. Show that $$ \max \left\{\left|X_{1}\right|, \ldots,\left|X_{n}\right|\right\} \stackrel{\mathrm{P}}{\longrightarrow} a $$ for $ n \rightarrow \infty $.

**Attempt/Idea 2**:
For each $\varepsilon > 0$ we want to show that

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\max\left\{\left|X_1\right|,\ldots,\left|X_n\right|\right\} - a\right| > \varepsilon\right) \rightarrow 0 \quad \text{for} \quad n \rightarrow \infty
$$

Since $\max \left\{\left|X_1\right|,\ldots,\left|X_n\right|\right\} \leq a$ holds, we can reformulate above probability:

$$
\mathbb{P} \left( \max \left\{\left|X_1\right|,\ldots,\left|X_n\right|\right\} \leq a - \varepsilon \right)
$$

Since $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ are independent and identically distributed, it holds:

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\max \left\{\left|X_1\right|,\ldots,\left|X_n\right|\right\} \leq a - \varepsilon\right) = \mathbb{P}\left(\left|X_1\right| \leq a - \varepsilon\right)^n
$$

We can calculate the probability on the right-hand side by distinguishing the different cases for $x$:

1. if $x \leq 0$, then $\left|X_1\right| \leq a - \varepsilon$ is always satisfied, since $a - \varepsilon > 0$ holds.
2. if $0 < x \leq a - \varepsilon$, then $\left|X_1\right| \leq a - \varepsilon$ is also satisfied, since $\left|X_1\right|$ takes values in the interval $[-a, a]$.
3. if $x > a - \varepsilon$, then $\left|X_1\right| \leq a - \varepsilon$ is not satisfied, since $\left|X_1\right|$ takes values in the interval $[-a, a]$.

It follows:

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|X_1\right| \leq a - \varepsilon\right) = \frac{a - \varepsilon}{2a}
$$

Thus we obtain:

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\max\left\{\left|X_1\right|,\ldots,\left|X_n\right|\right\} \leq a - \varepsilon\right) = \left(\frac{a - \varepsilon}{2a}\right)^n
$$

For $n \rightarrow \infty$ this expression goes to 0 because $a - \varepsilon < 2a$ and the exponent becomes larger and larger. Therefore

$$
\max\left\{\left|X_1\right|,\ldots,\left|X_n\right|\right\}
$$

in the limit against (a) in the likelihood.

**Attempt/Idea 1**:

I want to use the following theorem from my script:

$
X_{n} \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow} c} , c \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow X_{n} \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\stackrel{P}{\rightarrow} c}  
$

To use it, I tried this:

Let be $ Y_{n}:=\max \left\{\left|X_{1}\right|,\left|X_{2}\right|, \ldots,\left|X_{n}\right|\right\} $.

It applies:

$
\begin{aligned}
F_{Y_{n}}(x) & =P\left(Y_{n} \leq x\right)=P\left(\max \left\{\left|X_{1}\right|, \ldots,\left|X_{n}\right|\right\} \leq x\right)= \\
& =P\left(\left|X_{1}\right| \leq x,\left|X_{2}\right| \leq x, \ldots, \left|X_{n}\right| \leq x\right) \\
& = \prod \limits_{k=1}^{n} P\left(\left|X_{k}\right| \leq x\right)= ?
\end{aligned}
$

But how to proceed now?

Comment: As the distribution of each $X_k$ is known, the next step is to calculate $P(|X_k| \leq x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $X_k$ has the same distribution as $X_1$, $\mathbb P\left(\left|X_{k}\right| \leq x\right)=\mathbb P\left(\left|X_{1}\right| \leq x\right)$, which can be computed by distinguishing the cases $x\leqslant 0$, $0<x\leqslant a$ and $x>a$.

Alternatively, it is possible to show directly the convergence in probability by noticing that for each $\varepsilon>0$,
$$
\mathbb P\left(\left\lvert \max \left\{\left|X_{1}\right|, \ldots,\left|X_{n}\right|\right\}-a\right\rvert>\varepsilon\right)
=\mathbb P\left( \max \left\{\left|X_{1}\right|, \ldots,\left|X_{n}\right|\right\} \leqslant a-\varepsilon\right)
$$
(which is due to the fact that $\max \left\{\left|X_{1}\right|, \ldots,\left|X_{n}\right|\right\} \leqslant a$) and compute explicitely the last probability in a similar way as the other approach.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ \max \left\{\left|X_{1}\right|, \ldots,\left|X_{n}\right|\right\}\leq a$ and $P( \max \left\{\left|X_{1}\right|, \ldots,\left|X_{n}\right|\right\} \leq a-\epsilon) =(\frac {a-2\epsilon}{ 2a})^{n} \to 0$ for every $\epsilon \in (0,a)$.